# best way of testing HD throughput for random reads on linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, benchmark

Is there a benchmark program I can use to measure random read speeds of a vps without interference from the kernel cache? Also looking for something where you can change the read sizes say 4k-64k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/) and/or [bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) to benchmark. If you're solid on what you need to test, both tools are customizable to those requirements.

For iozone, try something like the following to run a single-threaded random read/write test with a 4k record size using a 4 Gigabyte file.

Run this from the directory you wish to test: `iozone -t1 -i2 -r4k -s4g`

Comment: I tried running iozone but I keep getting "iozone.DUMMY.0: No such file or directory". Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: Make sure you are running iozone in a directory that you have write permissions to.

Comment: I get the same error as @incognito2. I'm running iozone from my desktop folder which I definitely have write permissions for.

Comment: I have the same error, I have all permissions and available space.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have to use `iozone -t1 -i0 -i2 -r4k -s4g` for the test in ewwhite answer to run.
This -i0 (write test) is required before a read test as noted in https://superuser.com/questions/365588/iozone-runs-fail-with-no-such-file-or-directory-errors :

> The iozone manual states that if you're going to use the `-i` argument, you need to include `-i 0` in order to have files to test against. In your case, use `-i 0 -i 2` to get your write test. If you don't specify that test, the other tests have no file to work with and you'll get the error you see.

Or you can run with `-w -f <file>` and do an initial `-i 0` run. Then the file will be there for the following `-i 2` test.